# Output format of numbers is not sorted java mapreduce program

Tags: java, mapreduce

The number output of reducer gives the output as dictionary order like it shows 2 after 19 and 3 after 29 but it should be in the number wise order. please help in solving this issue.

```
Mapper code:
public class SPMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
{
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        //1 1.232
        //1 1.45
        String s = value.toString();
        String[] pat = s.split(" ");

        String patent = pat[0];
        context.write(new Text(patent),new IntWritable(1));
        context.write(new Text(patent.),IntWritable(1));
        //1, 1
        //1, 1
    }

}

Reducer code:
public class SPReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{

    protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> 
    values, Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>.Context arg2) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    Integer y=0;
    //1, {1,1,1,1,1}
    for(IntWritable x: values)
    {
        y=y+ Integer.parseInt(x.toString());
    }
    arg2.write(key,new IntWritable(y));
    }

}
```

the reducer of mapreduce program gives the output as below:

```
(number,count)
0 1
1 3
11 3
12 5
.
.
.
19 4
2 4
```

but the acutal output should be as

```
(number,count)
0 1
1 3
2 4
.
.
.
11 3
12 5
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: ... With no code how do you expect an answer? The only way a sort would do that is if you're sorting strings, not numbers.

Comment: attached the code, please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Every reducer outputs the keys in sorted order. If you want ALL output to be sorted you should run your job with a single reducer

Comment: yes here i used only one reducer

Comment: and yeah, actually in this case the output has been properly sorted by key as correctly mentioned by Dave Newton since the keys are strings not numbers

Comment: is there any chance i could get the required output as mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

A TreeMap would work to put the stuff in sorted order by keys.

```
Map<Text, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<>(); 
sorted.put(key,new IntWritable(y));
```

To get the output

```
for (Map.Entry<Text, Integer> entry : sorted.entrySet())  
            System.out.println("number:" + entry.getKey() +  
                         ", count:" + entry.getValue());
```